# C# Lottery odds to win

Tags: c#, function, combinations, factorial

I have to make this problem: "You want to participate in the game of chance 6 out of 49 with only one variant and you want to know what chances you will win:category I (6 numbers),category II (5 numbers),category III (4 numbers). Write a application that receive as input data the total number of balls, the number of balls drawn and then prints the chances of winning with an accuracy of 10 decimals if played with a single variant". An example will be 40, 5 and II (5 numbers) and the result is 0.0002659542. I know the formula to this is n!/k!*(n-k)! but the program I've made only works for category I.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string extract = Console.ReadLine();
    int category1 = category(extract);
    switch (category1)
    {
        case 6:
            calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
            break;
        case 5:
            calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
            break;
        case 4:
            calculateTheOddsToWin(n, k, extract);
            break;
    }

}
static void calculateTheOddsToWin(int n, int k, string extract)
{
    double comb = combination(n, k);
    decimal solution = (decimal)(1 / comb);
    decimal round = Math.Round(solution, 10);
    Console.WriteLine(round);
}
static double combination(int n, int k)
{
    double factN = factorial(n);
    double factK = factorial(k);
    double factNK = substractFactorialNK(n, k);
    double combination = factN / (factNK * factK);
    return combination;
}

static double factorial(int n)
{
    double factorialN = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        factorialN *= i;
    }
    return factorialN;
}
static double substractFactorialNK(int n, int k)
{
    double factorialNK = 1;
    int substract = n - k;
    for (int i = 1; i <= substract; i++)
    {
        factorialNK *= i;
    }
    return factorialNK;
}
static int category(string extract)
{
    if (extract == "I")
    {
        return 6;
    }
    else if (extract == "II")
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else if (extract == "III")
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Any ideeas on how to solve this?

Comment: You need to debug your code properly, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line and examine the state as you go. If you still can't work it out, you need to relay to use exactly where and how the code doesn't behave as expected. If it does behave as expected but still doesn't produce the right result then the issue is with the logic, so forget the code and pick up a pen and paper and work out the logic manually first.

Comment: Your code ignores the category selected by the user (probably because your formula only works for category I). You don't have a C# problem, you have a mathematical problem. You need to solve that one first (https://math.stackexchange.com can help), then you can think about implementing that solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was a math problem, so after research, I did it like this:
private static double Factorial(int value)
{
double result = 1.0;

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= value; ++i)
        result *= i;

    return result;
}

static double Combinations(int x, int y)
{
    return Factorial(x) / Factorial(y) / Factorial(x - y);
}
private static double Chances(int a, int t, int c)
{
    return Combinations(t, t - c + 1) *
           Combinations(a - t, c - 1) /
           Combinations(a, t);
}

public static void Main()
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int k=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string category=Console.ReadLine();
    if (category == "I")
    {
        int categoryInt = 1;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F10}", Chances(n, k, categoryInt)));
    }
    if (category == "II")
    {
        int categoryInt = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F10}", Chances(n, k, categoryInt)));
    }
    if (category == "III")
    {
        int categoryInt = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:F10}", Chances(n, k, categoryInt)));
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).